# Missing { inserted in \chapter*{} command

Tags: errors, chapters

I’m having an error with this line in my main.tex code:

`\chapter*{abstract}`

Similar for other preamble chapters like my dedication/ acknowledgments etc, but not with numbered chapters in the main body of my thesis.

I’m using overleaf.  Documentclass is report.

Despite the fact that it comes through as an error, it compiles fine and creates a .pdf which looks the way that I want it to.

I can get rid of the error by removing the ‘*’ symbol.  However, the preamble chapter will then be numbered, will appear in the ToC and I don’t want it to!

The easy thing to do would be to ignore it and crack on as it still creates a .pdf, but I’m keen to try to be error free if I can!

I’m using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[inner=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
```

My preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, margin=15mm]{report}

% Loads files with important stuff in them
\input{System/packages.tex}
\input{System/Acronyms.tex}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

% Sets Up Formatting
\makeglossaries
\pagenumbering{roman}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\centering\uppercase\Large\bfseries}{CHAPTER \thechapter:}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\leftalign\large\bfseries}{\thesection \ \sectiontitle}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\leftalign\large\textit}{\thesubsection \ \subsectiontitle}{}{}
‘’’
```

Comment: Untested but \uppercase will probably break stuff there.

Comment: Yep!!! That’s the ticket.  I’ve removed \uppercase and the error has gone!  Many thanks!